# Получить значение по ключу из .config

Tags: c#, xml, config

Есть App.config файл принадлежащий другому приложению. Текст конфигурации записан в `XmlDocument`  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="currentVersion" value="1.0"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Нужно получить в `value` как это сделать ? `ConfigurationManager` не работает тк это App.config другого приложения. Пытаюсь сделать так :

```
            var stringApp = (XMLCONFIG.GetElementById("currentVersion").Value);
```

Исключение = ссылка на обьект не указывает на экземпляр обьекта. Как же получить `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ошибка в том, что метод  OpenExeConfiguration ожидает путь до .EXE а не до самого файла конфигурации. А для того что бы работать именно с конфигурацией не хватало `ExeConfigurationFileMap`

Правильно было написать так :

```
 var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
 configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename ="path to EXE";
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
 var confstring = config.AppSettings.Settings["currentVersion"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

ConfigurationManager все же может вам помочь. Если это исполняемое приложение то можно так попробовать

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguratio(string pathToExe);
```

Или, если речь идет о сборке, которая загружена в текущий домен, то возможен такой вариант.

```
var assemblyLocation = typeof(TargetType).GetType().Assembly.Location
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguratio(assemblyLocation);
```

Comment: Что мне делать после того как я получу в config обьект Configuration ?

Comment: дальше копай в xmlreader

Comment: @Garrus_En А в чем помощь то если и так текст файла app уже записан в XmlDocument ?

Comment: Не нужно config копать xmlreader. Для этого есть ConfigurationManager. xmlreader - не учитыват "родительские" настройки. Да и "детки" могут быть как с так и без web.config.

Comment: @nick_n_a если я получил обьект Configuration  то как с ним работает ConfigurationManager ?

Comment: @Сергей попробуйте считать ваше значение так var value = config.AppSettings.Settings["currentVersion"].Value

Comment: config это объект типа Configuration

Comment: Секция AppSettings читается так: `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["currentVersion"] `  Ещё доступно ConnectionStrings открыто, остальные секции config читаются через `WebConfigurationManager.GetSection`. Configuration  вам пока что не нужен.

Comment: А разве WebConfiguration работает не с текущим web.config? Тут несколько другая ситуация приведена в вопросе. Выдержка из MSDN Using WebConfigurationManager is the preferred way to work with configuration files related to Web applications. For client applications, use the ConfigurationManager class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4